# Integration over the cube

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

I have the following exercise:

Integrate the $g=x \cdot y \cdot z$ over the cube that is on the first octant and that is bounded from the levels $x=1, y=1, z=1$.

Could you give me some hint what I am supposed to do?

I got stuck right now...

I have the following formula for the surface integral in my notes:
$$z=f(x,y)$$
$$\iint_R g(x,y,z) d \sigma=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}dxdy$$
How can I apply this formula in this case?

Comment: Can you integrate for $g=x.y$ or $g=x$ over that cube?

Comment: @HoseynHeydari I have the following formula for the surface integral in my notes:
$$z=f(x,y)$$
$$\iint_R g(x,y,z) d \sigma=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}dxdy$$
How can I apply this formula in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is to integrate a function over a surface.
It does not apply in this case since you're integrating over a volume instead of over a surface.

You are supposed to multiply your function with an infinitesimal volume element and integrate over the octant.
That is:
$$\iiint_{Octant} g(x,y,z) dV = \iiint_{Octant} xyz\ dxdydz$$

Comment: Ahaa...If I had to integrate the function over the surface, I would have to add the integrals of the $6$ sides, right? Is this because I take the projection of the surface each time on an other plane? I mean once on the plane $xz$, then on the plane $xy$, and then on the plane $yz$?

Comment: Yep. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

$$
\iiint \limits_V xyzdV=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1xyzdxdydz.
$$

Comment: I have the following formula for the surface integral in my notes:
$$z=f(x,y)$$
$$\iint_R g(x,y,z) d \sigma=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}dxdy$$
Or do we have to use a triple integral, as you did?

Comment: Is your integral over cube's surface or over cube?

Comment: I have to integrate the function $g$ over the cube. Since this is in the chapter of surface integral, I suppose that I have to use the formula that I wrote in my last comment. Or not?

Comment: In that case can you see that $\iint\limits_S xyz dS=3\int_0^1\int_0^1xydxdy$?

Comment: But how can I use this formula in this case? Which is now $z=f(x,y)$?

Comment: Can you see that integral over cube's surface equals sum of 6 integrals over cube's sides?

Comment: I got stuck right now... To calculate the integral over a surface, we calculate the integral over the projection of this surface at the plane. Is this correct?

Comment: No, of course not. But I didn't say it.

Comment: For 3 sides of cube which in the planes $xOy,xOz, and~ yOz$ integral over those sides equal $0$, because function equals $0$.

Comment: It follows from definition. Well, can you calculate integral over cube side for which $z = 1$?

Comment: I haven't understood why we have to add the integrals of the $6$ sides... :/

Comment: Is this because I take the projection of the surface each time on an other plane? I mean once on the plane $xz$, then on the plane $xy$, and then on the plane $yz$?